# Instance on Points with curves problem

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, instances

First of all: excuse my bad english :-D

i have a little problem over here. i want to generate curve circles with "instance on points" on a curve rectangle.

This is what i want to have:
[image: Circle1]
[image: Circle2]

But with the the "instance on points" node i will get this. It seems that die vertices are flipped. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

[image: Circle3]
[image: Circle4]
[image: Circle5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a *Realize Instances* node after the *Instances on Points*.